# Generating MD5 Hash

Tags: java, security, aes, md5

I have a password that is sent into me which is encrypted using AES with an MD5 hash based on a numeric ID

From the request, I can get hold of the id in my database with other attributes
So on the server side, I need to get the id, get the MD5 hash based on that id and decrpyt the password using the AES algorithm and the generated MD5 hash.

I am using the following code to get the MD5 hash

```
 try {
        byte[] bytesOfMessage = id.getBytes("UTF-8");
        log.error "bytesOfMessage length: " + bytesOfMessage.length
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);

        md5Value = new String(thedigest);
        log.error "md5Value length: " + md5Value.length()
        log.error "md5Value bytes length: " + md5Value.getBytes().length
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        log.error "[getMD5EncryptionKey]UnsupportedEncodingException: " + e;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        log.error "[getMD5EncryptionKey]NoSuchAlgorithmException: " + e;
    }
```

The md5Value length is 16 based on an id of 1 but when I get the bytes from this md5value, there are 34 bytes

When I go to decrypt the password using this MD5 hash and the  javax.crypto.Cipher library, I get the following message

java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 34 bytes

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

The code I use to decrypt the message is as follows

```
  try {
        byte [] encryptionKeyBytes = md5EncryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKeyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decodedValue = new Base64().decode(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decodedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        log.error "[getDecryptedValue] InvalidKeyException: " + e
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        log.error "[getDecryptedValue] InvalidKeyException: " + e
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        log.error "[getDecryptedValue] InvalidKeyException: " + e
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        log.error "[getDecryptedValue] InvalidKeyException: " + e
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        log.error "[getDecryptedValue] InvalidKeyException: " + e
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error "[getDecryptedValue] InvalidKeyException: " + e
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ist that the string is hexadecimal. I would recommend you to use the apache commons-code package. There you have a utility class for hashes.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html

Then you can use the following code:

```
String md5 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(id);
// or
byte[] md5 = DigestUtils.md5(id);
```

Comment: wasnt aware of this library, used it and its doing the trick. cheers guys

Answer (score 1):

The byte-array you get is an md5-hash but with hexadecimal values.

You can't just cast your array to a string. You have to convert it with an algorithm that takes those hexa-values and gives you the proper string.

Below you can see an algorithm to get the 32bit MD5Hash-String, maybe this helps:

```
public String createHashString(String s)
{

    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] bytesOfMessage = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);


        String hexString = "";
        for(byte bi : thedigest)
        {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & bi);
            if (hex.length() == 1) {

                hexString += "0";
            }
            hexString += (hex);
        }

        return hexString;

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This `md5Value = new String(thedigest)` is your issue. `thedigest` is binary and the String class can't figure out it's encoding (cause it has none), this causes the binary value to get mangled when you try to get it back out of the String. This is why `md5Value.getBytes().length` is 34 bytes. Create the `SecretKeySpec` directly from `thedigest`.

```
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(thedigest, "AES");
```

The AES key needs to be the actual 16 byte binary value of the MD5 hash.

Note as well, `new String(someBinaryByteArray).getBytes()` will *sometimes* return the same bytes you put in, but it's all dependent on the input. Your input id value illustrates this. Another example:

```
String id = "test";
byte[] bytesOfMessage = id.getBytes("UTF-8");
System.out.println("bytesOfMessage length: " + bytesOfMessage.length);
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);
System.out.println("thedigest Hex: " + Hex.encodeHexString(thedigest));
String md5Value = new String(thedigest);
System.out.println("md5Value length: " + md5Value.length());
System.out.println("md5Value bytes length: " + md5Value.getBytes().length);
System.out.println("md5Value Hex: " + Hex.encodeHexString(md5Value.getBytes()));

Output:
bytesOfMessage length: 4
thedigest Hex: 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
md5Value length: 16
md5Value bytes length: 16
md5Value Hex: 093f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

`098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6` != `093f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6`